# I want to make a accordion, and I want it to function like a site I found

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

It has to be able to run in Wordpress, and it also has to be able to house as many "sections" as I wish. It also has to be able to have multiple instances of the accordion with different information in each. The site that I got the idea from was http://www.steppenwolf.org/Plays-Events/.

I have next to no experience with javascript, but am proficient with HTML and CSS.

I am NOT asking you to make this for me, only help me in the building of such a thing.

I want to be able to use an unordered list to form the accordion:

```
<ul class="accordion-1">
    <li class="accordion-item-1"></li>
    <li class="accordion-item-2"></li>
    <li class="accordion-item-3"></li>
    <li class="accordion-item-4"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="accordion-2">
    <li class="accordion-item-5"></li>
etc...
```

Comment: Have you even tried googling for one?

Comment: None of them do or look like what I want. That's why I'm asking for help to build one.

Comment: It's best if you learn some basic Javascript/jQuery before tackling this.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise looking to see if there is already a plugin available. I did a quick search and found a jQueryUI one  - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-ui-widgets/

This will allow you to use the [Accordian plugin](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: That one is good, but not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a horizontal accordion like the site that i listed in my post.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - this isn't exactly the same but it is horizontal! - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slywrapper/

Comment: This might work in the mean time. :) Thanks :D I'm still looking to replicate the website though, as it is a good accordion for the purpose that I need it for.

Comment: Take a look at the free themes as well - some of them have this type of thing already baked in

Comment: It didn't work, i have no way to put it into my wordpress page. I am running Wordpress 3.5.1, and it is made to go up to wordpress 3.4.2

Comment: Have you tried it with 3.5.1? It might work - the compatible up to is set either by the developer or what the version was at time of commit - I can't remember which exactly.

Comment: I did try it :o but it doens't provide a way to insert it, and the shortcode doen't allow for me to just set content, i have to create a catagory for it to pull from...